# Removing content: " » "; with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using Yoast Breadcrumb Plugin for a website and I need to remove a line from the html which is generated by the plugin.

Currently my breadcrumb looks like this:
Home » » Page 1 » Project Page

```
<p id="breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/">Home</a> » 
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com"></a> » 
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/project-page-1/">Page 1</a> 
    » Project Page
</p>
```

As you can see the second link has no text and I don't want to display that whole line including the ».

I have tried the following CSS (with no luck!) is there something more I can do to remove this?

```
p#breadcrumb:first-child a::after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: could you  please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: That's not what `::after` means.  You can't do that.

Comment: does this link help? http://www.nextgelectrical.com/projectprofiles/citipower-office-fit-out/ - its on Wordpress so I dont think I can really duplicate it as it is plugin generated?

Comment: if you can see ">>" in your HTML then it's not generated by CSS `:after`

Comment: If you are sure you are targeting the right pseudo-element, try to erase its content with content : "";

Comment: I think you might need to use js for this solution if you cannot alter the html markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to target separate parts of text inside an element with CSS (except the first letter, but that's not relevant here). Your best option would be to modify the plugin HTML, unfortunately.

One rather dirty trick might help you out: make the empty link take up negative space, causing the first and second » to overlap so it kind of looks like one (just a little bolder):

```
#breadcrumbs a:empty {
    margin-left: -12px;
}
```

Note that this may cause different results depending on the font size. I really can't recommend this trick but if you are 100% sure you can't edit the HTML this might just do.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yrj594oo/

Comment: Good answer. +1 for correctly interpreting the question. @LisaJaffe I thought you wanted to *remove* all `»` content as per your question.

Comment: Interesting solution. It does make the first » symbol look a little bold in Chrome (as unfortunately they don't perfectly line up), but unless you stare at it for a while you really don't notice. I wouldn't like to be the developer who has to cater for this across multiple browsers and devices though!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this without also hiding the "Project Page" text. If you don't care about the "Project Page" text, you can simply:

```css
#breadcrumb {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 0;
}

#breadcrumb a {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<p id="breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/">Home</a> » 
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com"></a> » 
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/project-page-1/">Page 1</a> 
    » Project Page
</p>
```

Otherwise your only option will be to modify the plugin itself - ideally to wrap the "Project Page" text in an element of its own which you can override the font size on, or better still actually convert those `»` characters into pseudo-elements which can be disabled by setting them to `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proud of this solution but the only way I can think to do this with CSS is a bit of a hack but you could draw a box *over* the `»` to mask it.

```css
#breadcrumb a {
    position:relative;
}
#breadcrumb a:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:100%;
    background:white;
    height:1em;
    width:.8em;
}
#breadcrumb a:empty {
    width:0px; overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<p id="breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/">Home</a> » 
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com"></a> » 
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/project-page-1/">Page 1</a> 
    » Project Page
</p>
```